# How to adjust Google Chrome predictors?

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to edit values in Google Chrome predictors ( chrome://predictors/ )?
I've been looking for it along other database files in AppData directory with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Network Action Predictor"` is SQLite DB that contains predictors data.

Tested on Google Chrome version 42.0.2300.2 dev-m.

Comment: any idea where it's located on OSX ?

Comment: @artmees Check folders mentioned in [this article](http://crunchify.com/how-to-purge-all-your-google-chrome-user-data-on-mac-os-x/) and see if any of them conatins `Network Action Predictor` file (no extension, at least on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

On Macs, this is stored in a SQLite DB at `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Network Action Predictor`